# How to group by records in descending order?

Tags: group-by, sybase

I have set of records that should be group by user id, and then records should show up in descending order from highest to lowest year id. Here is example of the data I have in the table:

```
SELECT user_id, year_id FROM tbl_users WHERE section_id = 3590 AND year_id < 30
```

Query output:

```
User_ID  Year_ID
 ZK0616     10
 ZK0616     11
 ZK0616     12
 JP0204     13
 JP0204     24
 JP0204     25
 JP0204     26
 JP0204     27
 JP0204     28
 JP0204     29
```

I wrote this query in hope to get desired output. Here is the query:

```
SELECT user_id, max(year_id)
FROM tbl_users 
WHERE section_id = 3590 AND year_id < 30
GROUP BY user_id
```

Query output:

```
User_ID  Year_ID
ZK0616      12
JP0204      29
```

The output above still is not providing desired output. I would like to see Year_ID in descending order (from highest to lowest like this):

```
User_ID  Year_ID
JP0204      29
ZK0616      12
```

I can't use `ORDER BY` since this query will be used as a sub query in `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, max(year_id)
    FROM tbl_users 
    WHERE section_id = 3590 AND year_id < 30
    GROUP BY user_id
) tbl2
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to sort the records by year_id with group by. I use sybase database in my project.

Comment: if the result set is going to be used in a (left) join then what difference does the ordering make?  either move the `order by` clause 'up' to the parent query or provide more details as to why the results of this sub-query **need** to be sorted

Comment: The result set from left join has to be ordered by because I need the most recent record from the result set.

Comment: assuming you want any row in the case of multiple rows having the same `Year_ID` ... consider rewriting this sub-query to pull just the record having `Year_ID = max(Year_ID)` ...

Comment: I provided data sample that should make that clear. There is always one record for each year_id. I want to pull unique user id's and get the row with the most recent/highest year_id.

Comment: regardless of the number of rows generated by the sub-query you've stated that you only want **one** row for the `left join`, ie, you don't care about any `User_IDs` that don't contain the `max(Year_ID)` ... so adjust your query logic to find the `max(Year_ID)` and the (top 1) `User_ID` where `Year_ID = max(Year_ID)`; something like: `select top 1 User_ID,Year_ID from tbl_users where ... and Year_ID = (select max(Year_ID) from tbl_users where ... )`